# Java Swing UI not showing up when run

Tags: java, swing

I do not know if this is a duplicate question but when I run my java swing GUI code nothing shows up even with all the visibility's set as true. I am new to java swing gui creation so any help would be greatly appreciated. here is my pages class

```
class Pages {
    public static void Welcome_Screen() {
//         Create the main screen for adding the other panels and buttons
        JPanel Main_Screen = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints Main_Screen_Constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
//         Set the size of the Main_Screen
        Main_Screen.setSize(1280, 720);

//         Create the three panels needed to make this work
//         Set the layouts as GridBagLayout and create the constraints needed
        JPanel Side_Panel = new JPanel();
        Side_Panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints Side_Panel_Constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        JPanel Profile_Panel = new JPanel();
        Profile_Panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints Profile_Panel_Constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        JPanel Button_Panel = new JPanel();
        Button_Panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints Button_Panel_Constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        JPanel About_Panel = new JPanel();
        About_Panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints About_Panel_Constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

//         Change the sides of the panels to fit them correctly
        Side_Panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 720));
        Side_Panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 720));
        Side_Panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(150, 1080));
        Profile_Panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        Button_Panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 620));
        About_Panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1180, 720));

//        Change the border types to null
        Side_Panel.setBorder(null);
        Profile_Panel.setBorder(null);
        Button_Panel.setBorder(null);
        About_Panel.setBorder(null);

//        Create the Profile_Panel items
        ImageIcon Profile_Icon = new ImageIcon("Images/Profile_Icon.png");
        JButton Profile_Button = new JButton(Profile_Icon);
        Profile_Button.setSize(100, 100);
        Profile_Panel_Constraints.gridx = 0;
        Profile_Panel_Constraints.gridy = 0;
        Profile_Panel.add(Profile_Button, Profile_Panel_Constraints);

//        Create the Buttons for the Button_Panel
        ImageIcon Java_Icon = new ImageIcon("Images/Java_Icon.png");
        JButton Java_Button = new JButton(Java_Icon);
        Java_Button.setSize(100, 155);
        Button_Panel_Constraints.gridx = 0;
        Button_Panel_Constraints.gridy = 0;
        Button_Panel.add(Java_Button, Button_Panel_Constraints);

        ImageIcon Python_Icon = new ImageIcon("Images/Python_Icon.png");
        JButton Python_Button = new JButton(Python_Icon);
        Python_Button.setSize(100, 155);
        Button_Panel_Constraints.gridy = 1;
        Button_Panel.add(Python_Button, Button_Panel_Constraints);

        ImageIcon CPP_Icon = new ImageIcon("Images/CPP_Icon.png");
        JButton CPP_Button = new JButton(CPP_Icon);
        CPP_Button.setSize(100, 155);
        Button_Panel_Constraints.gridy = 2;
        Button_Panel.add(CPP_Button);

        ImageIcon CS_Icon = new ImageIcon("Images/CS_Icon.png");
        JButton CS_Button = new JButton(CS_Icon);
        CS_Button.setSize(100, 155);
        Button_Panel_Constraints.gridy = 3;
        Button_Panel.add(CS_Button);

//        About panel set up
        About_Panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JButton About_Panel_PlaceHolder = new JButton();
        About_Panel_PlaceHolder.setSize(1180, 720);
        About_Panel_Constraints.gridx = 0;
        About_Panel_Constraints.gridy = 0;
        About_Panel.add(About_Panel_PlaceHolder);

//        Add the panels to the Main_Screen
        Side_Panel_Constraints.gridx = 0;
        Side_Panel_Constraints.gridy = 0;
        Side_Panel.add(Profile_Panel, Side_Panel_Constraints);
        Side_Panel_Constraints.gridy = 1;
        Side_Panel.add(Button_Panel, Side_Panel_Constraints);
        Main_Screen_Constraints.gridx = 0;
        Main_Screen_Constraints.gridy = 0;
        Main_Screen.add(Side_Panel, Main_Screen_Constraints);
        Main_Screen_Constraints.gridx = 1;
        Main_Screen.add(About_Panel, Main_Screen_Constraints);

//        Set the Main_Screen visibility to true
        Side_Panel.setVisible(true);
        About_Panel.setVisible(true);
        Main_Screen.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

I understand that the code probably isn't orthodox programming as I am still learning how to do it. But any help with the UI not showing up would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to put all this in a JFrame

Comment: 1) Variable names should NOT start with upper case characters. I have never seen a text book or tutorial use a capital letter. Follow standards. 2) you need to add the components to a frame and make the frame viaible. 3) Start with simple working example that will show you how to better structure your code to reduce problems in the future. For example start with the demos on [Using Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Thank you both, I apologize for the upper case letters.

Comment: Java naming conventions also forbid underscores in class names, methods, and variables. In fact, everything but constants (which should be all upper case).

Comment: Alright good to know, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your Problem is that all java swing applications are in a Frame. Panel is inside a frame.

Your solution would be :

```
class Pages extends JFrame {
    public Pages() {
//         Create the main screen for adding the other panels and buttons
        JPanel Main_Screen = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints Main_Screen_Constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
//         Set the size of the Main_Screen
        Main_Screen.setSize(1280, 720);

//         Create the three panels needed to make this work
//         Set the layouts as GridBagLayout and create the constraints needed
        JPanel Side_Panel = new JPanel();
        Side_Panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints Side_Panel_Constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        JPanel Profile_Panel = new JPanel();
        Profile_Panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints Profile_Panel_Constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        JPanel Button_Panel = new JPanel();
        Button_Panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints Button_Panel_Constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

        JPanel About_Panel = new JPanel();
        About_Panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints About_Panel_Constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

//         Change the sides of the panels to fit them correctly
        Side_Panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 720));
        Side_Panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 720));
        Side_Panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(150, 1080));
        Profile_Panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        Button_Panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 620));
        About_Panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1180, 720));

//        Change the border types to null
        Side_Panel.setBorder(null);
        Profile_Panel.setBorder(null);
        Button_Panel.setBorder(null);
        About_Panel.setBorder(null);

//        Create the Profile_Panel items
        ImageIcon Profile_Icon = new ImageIcon("Images/Profile_Icon.png");
        JButton Profile_Button = new JButton(Profile_Icon);
        Profile_Button.setSize(100, 100);
        Profile_Panel_Constraints.gridx = 0;
        Profile_Panel_Constraints.gridy = 0;
        Profile_Panel.add(Profile_Button, Profile_Panel_Constraints);

//        Create the Buttons for the Button_Panel
        ImageIcon Java_Icon = new ImageIcon("Images/Java_Icon.png");
        JButton Java_Button = new JButton(Java_Icon);
        Java_Button.setSize(100, 155);
        Button_Panel_Constraints.gridx = 0;
        Button_Panel_Constraints.gridy = 0;
        Button_Panel.add(Java_Button, Button_Panel_Constraints);

        ImageIcon Python_Icon = new ImageIcon("Images/Python_Icon.png");
        JButton Python_Button = new JButton(Python_Icon);
        Python_Button.setSize(100, 155);
        Button_Panel_Constraints.gridy = 1;
        Button_Panel.add(Python_Button, Button_Panel_Constraints);

        ImageIcon CPP_Icon = new ImageIcon("Images/CPP_Icon.png");
        JButton CPP_Button = new JButton(CPP_Icon);
        CPP_Button.setSize(100, 155);
        Button_Panel_Constraints.gridy = 2;
        Button_Panel.add(CPP_Button);

        ImageIcon CS_Icon = new ImageIcon("Images/CS_Icon.png");
        JButton CS_Button = new JButton(CS_Icon);
        CS_Button.setSize(100, 155);
        Button_Panel_Constraints.gridy = 3;
        Button_Panel.add(CS_Button);

//        About panel set up
        About_Panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JButton About_Panel_PlaceHolder = new JButton();
        About_Panel_PlaceHolder.setSize(1180, 720);
        About_Panel_Constraints.gridx = 0;
        About_Panel_Constraints.gridy = 0;
        About_Panel.add(About_Panel_PlaceHolder);

//        Add the panels to the Main_Screen
        Side_Panel_Constraints.gridx = 0;
        Side_Panel_Constraints.gridy = 0;
        Side_Panel.add(Profile_Panel, Side_Panel_Constraints);
        Side_Panel_Constraints.gridy = 1;
        Side_Panel.add(Button_Panel, Side_Panel_Constraints);
        Main_Screen_Constraints.gridx = 0;
        Main_Screen_Constraints.gridy = 0;
        Main_Screen.add(Side_Panel, Main_Screen_Constraints);
        Main_Screen_Constraints.gridx = 1;
        Main_Screen.add(About_Panel, Main_Screen_Constraints);

//        Set the Main_Screen visibility to true
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout())//use te layout you want;
        this.add(Main_Screen);
        this.setTitle("My Java Swing App");
        this.setSize(500, 500);//you can also use .pack() to automatically set the size required
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//this one is very important
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static openMainWindow(){
        Pages frame = new Pages();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        openMainWindow();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, you also fixed the program hanging on close problem that I had (didn't mention it cause i figured i was forgetting something).

Comment: yeah `this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` this line ensures that it closes properly